# Consider the group of integers with addition. Is the following statement true.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

$H$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ if and only $H=m\mathbb{Z}$ for some positive integer $m$.

I know there is a similar statement to this and I know its proof but I want to check that the statement as I have written it precisely above is correct?

Could anyone confirm?

Comment: Consider $m = -1$.

Comment: Also $\{0\}$ is a subgroup.

Comment: @drhab: Isn't that the same as $m=0$?

Comment: @Nikolaj-K Yes, but the OP speaks of a **positive** integer.

Comment: @JohnHughes: Isn't that the same as $m=1$?

Comment: The statement, as it is, is true...but the weird condition "$\;m\;$ is a *positive* integer " can be confusing.

Comment: The statement is true if you replace "positive" with "non-negative".

Comment: No $m = -1$ is not a counter example. If you take $m = -1$ then $H = -\Bbb{Z} = \Bbb{Z}$ which is of the required form for some $m>0$, namely $m=1$

Comment: @JohnHughes I disagree. The statement does **not** say that $(-1)\mathbb Z$ is not a subgroup of $\mathbb Z$. That would be something like: "if $m\mathbb Z$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb Z$ then $m$ is not negative." That is not stated.

Comment: m = -1 is definitely not a counter example and (-1)Z = Z = (1) Z.  But m = 0 is.  0*Z = {0} which is a group.  If you replace "subgroup" with non-trivial subgroup it is true.  Or if you replace positive integer with integer, non-negative or non positive etc.

Comment: I’m in partial  agreement with @JohnHughes, for the reason that it’s almost always bad practice to stick a quantification at the end of the sentence, *most especially* when that quantification uses the dangerous word “some” (“any” is just as dangerous). If you, Ben B, had preposed the quantification, by saying “if and only if there is a nonnegative integer $m$ such that…”, then my friend John wouldn’t have had a leg to stand on.

Answer (score 1):

Yes true but $m$ should be non-negative in your question, say $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then consider the element with smallest positive absolute value, call it $a$, then H must be equal to $a\mathbb{Z}$.

Clearly  $a\mathbb{Z}$ is a subset of $H$ as $A\in H$.

Now suppose there exists an element $b\in H$ such that $b$ does not belong to $a\mathbb{Z}$.

We know $|b|>|a|$ by minimality of absolute value assumed earlier.

Now divide $b$ by $a$, the remainder must also be in $H$ which has an absolute value less than $a$, a contradiction, hence we are done.

Comment: In $2Z$, there is no single element with smallest absolute value. You might want to rephrase that as "consider the absolute values of all elements; let $a$ be the smallest nonzero absolute value."

Comment: ya.......forgot to write

Comment: Maybe this should be a separate question, but can the group structures of $m{\mathbb Z}$ be characterized in group theory? I'm having a bit of a problem with *"consider the element with smallest positive absolute value"*. The integers have a natural order, but do we have to use it to prove the theorem? Maybe it's something akin to *"the $a$ such that all $y$ have a representation $y=x+a$ where $x$ isn't $y$"*.

Comment: You have to solve for the m in H.  That involves finding the m that divides all other h in H.  Using order and the greatest common divisor seem the most efficient way to do that. There may be another but I don't see it right away.  There's no reason *not* to use order as we are talking $\mathbb Z$.  I .... hmm, can we prove G < H iff G = gH for some g in H?... no  of course we cant.

Comment: Z is basically the cyclic group with infinite order.  We can prove any subgroup of <a> is some <a^n>.  But to do that we need to use division principals of integers ... which is essence, no matter what word shuffling we do, boil down to "take the least element of"....

Comment: "but m should be non-negative in your question"  Or we could say H is a non-trivial group....

Answer (score 0):

Let's first start with H = {0} in this case m=0; that's all fine.

Let's try adding another element a in H. Then, -3a, -2a, -a, 2a, 3a, ... (all multiples of a) must also be in H, so in this case m=a.

Let's see what happens if you want to add another element other than a, such as b. In this case H must also contain all the multiples of b and all the linear combinations of a and b, i.e a+b, a-b, b-a, 2a-b, 2b-a, 2a+2b, 2b-2a etc... In this case let c be the greatest common divisor of a and b, m will be equal to c. Why? Because there must be some combination of x and y integers such that xa+by=c (Diofant equations, I believe) and that c will be the smallest element (other than 0)(you can't get any smaller) in H. Since c is in H, all multiples of c must also be in H, and since it was the smallest, thus making H=mZ. (If you reverse-engineer this, you will find that the greatest common divisor of any two elements in H also has to be in H. This also implies that if you find two relatively prime numbers in H, then H=Z (integer set)).

If you add more than 2 elements, keep taking the greatest common divisors of any two of them and replace that gcd with those two, keep repeating it and you will end up with a single number, that will be your m.

Why the greatest common divisor is the smallest number you can get out of the linear combination of two numbers:

Let's reanalyze the case with a and b. Let a=cx and b=cy where x and y are relatively prime, so c is their greatest common divisor. Compute z such that xz = 1 mod y. Such a z exists because x and y are relatively prime. More generally, since x^(y-1) = 1 mod y because of Fermat's theorem, z = x^(y-2) mod y so that xz = x*x^(y-2) = x^(y-1) = 1 mod y. (z doesn't exist when x and y are not relatively prime, because Fermat doesn't work there). This means for some t, xz = yt + 1, because this is how you convert modulo arithmetic to regular divison: p = r mod q --> p = qt + r. So, xz - yt = 1. Now, multiply each side with c: cxz - cyt = c --> az - bt = c. So, m=c and H=cZ. Notice that if a and b are already relatively prime, then c=1=m, H=1Z=Z. This is why if you have two relatively prime numbers in H, then H=Z.

Fun fact: This suggests that you can construct whole set of integer from two relatively prime numbers. However, this is possible because negative integers are allowed that helps convert (xz = yt + 1) into (xz - yt = 1). Otherwise given two relatively prime numbers x and y, you can only construct numbers starting from phi(xy)=phi(x)phi(y) onwards, if you are only allowed to use positive coefficients, where phi is the euler's totient function.

Answer (score 0):

Well, try it prove it.

$m\mathbb Z\subset \mathbb Z$ is easily shown to be a group.  Addition is still associative and the distributive law assures addition is closed.  $0$ is in the set and still and and additive identity and if $k = mj \in m\mathbb Z$ then so is $- = m(-j)$.

If $H$ is a subgroup let $m$ be the least positive integer in $H$.... Oh, wait...

First we have to determine if $H$ has any positive integers in $H$.  If it doesn't then $\{0\}$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb Z$ and $\{0\} \ne m\mathbb Z$ so the statement is simply not true.

We're done....

Except we can probably make a true statment from it.

Okay, lets say $H$ is a *non-trivial* subgroup if and only if $H = m\mathbb Z$ for some positive integer $m$. Let's try to prove that.

If $k \in H\subset \mathbb Z$ and $k \ne 0$ then $-k \in H$ and one of $k, -k$ is positive.  So if $H$ has any non-zero elements it has a positive integer.

Let $m$ be the lest positive integer in $H$.  By induction $m\mathbb Z = <m> \subset H$.

The statement (with the stipulation that $H$ is non-trivial, but not necessarily proper as $m=1$ will yield $H = 1\mathbb Z= \mathbb Z$) is true.

Let $k \in H \subset \mathbb Z$.  Then by division property there exist $q, r \in \mathbb Z$ so that $k = qm + r; 0 \le r < m$.

$r = k - qm \in H$.  $0 \le r < m$.  But $m$ is the least positive integer in $H$.  So $r = 0$.  So $k = qm \in m\mathbb Z$.  So $H \subset m\mathbb Z$.

So $H = m\mathbb Z$.